# Matrices: $A^7=I$ and $ABA^{-1}=B^2$, show that $B^k=I$ for some $k>0$.

Tags: matrices

Knowing that $A$ and $B$ are two invertible nxn matrices ($A≠I$, $B≠I$) such that:
$A^7=I$ and $ABA^{-1}=B^2$
Show that there is an integer $k>0$ such that $B^k=I$ and determine the lowest value for $k$.

I realize that performing $(ABA^{-1})^x)$ we get $AB^xA^{-1}$. I tried to form an argument replacing the $B^x$ to a something like $A^zB^y(A^{-1})^z$  and when $z$ is 7 or a multiple, we would be able to get away with $A$ using $A^7=I$. I think this idea of performing $(ABA^{-1})^x)$ is right and very useful, but I dont't know if the repetitive ideia of replacing $B^x$ is the best to prove the first part of the exercise. And thinking this way, I don't know if I can formalize a solid argument to find the lowest $k$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

Since $A^7 = I$, $$\begin{align}
B = & A^7BA^{-7}\\ 
= & A^6(ABA^{-1})A^{-6} = A^6B^2A^{-6}\\
= & A^5(AB^2A^{-1})A^{-5} = A^5(ABA^{-1})^2A^{-5}
= A^5(B^2)^2A^{-5} = A^5B^4A^{-5}\\
\vdots & \\
= & B^{2^7} = B^{128}
\end{align}$$
Since $B$ is invertible, multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ gives us $B^{127} = I$.

Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $B^m = I$, we have

$$B^m = I \land B^{127} = I \implies B^{\gcd(127,m)} = I$$
If $m < 127$, the fact $127$ is a primes forces $\gcd(127,m) = 1$. This leads to $B = I$ and contradict with what we are told $B \ne I$. As a result, $m \ge 127 \implies m = 127$.

Comment: (+1) nice answer. But please try not to give full solutions when OP has not shown their attempts :)

Comment: @J.G. $A^{7}=I$ is given

Comment: (+1) for such a neat answer

Comment: If $X^A=I$ and $X^B=I$, then $X^{mdc(A,B)}=I$ is always true or only if $X$ is invertible?

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho $X$ is invertible as $X^a = I$ for positive integer $a$ implies $\det(X)^a = 1 \implies \det(X) \ne 0$.

Comment: How can I prove that if $X^A=I$ and  $X^B=I$, then $X^{gcd(A,B)}=I$?

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho For any positive integers $a,b$, you can find integers $m, n$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = ma + nb$ (one can compute the gcd by euclidean algorithm,  one can extract the coefficients of $m,n$ by reversing the steps). This leads to $$X^{\gcd(a,b)} = X^{ma+nb} = (X^a)^m(X^b)^n = I^mI^n = I$$